# Как программно записать контакт на Sim

Tags: java, android

Записываю контакт так, но он записывает только на память телефона. Как же его записать на SIM?

```
String name = (String)nameEditText.getText().toString();
String phoneNumber = (String)phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString();

String result = null;

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
        ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.anddroid.contacts.sim")
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "SIM")
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                name).build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
        newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
        .build());

// Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact
try {
    getContentResolver().applyBatch("com.android.contacts", ops);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```